# Flutter Dart - dynamically set a property of a class

Tags: flutter, dart, class, parameter-passing

I would like to set the property of a class by passing a variable String name. How can I do that?

Similarly to the get method provided by @Chad Lamb

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person({this.age, this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> _toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }

  dynamic get(String propertyName) {
    var _mapRep = _toMap();
    if (_mapRep.containsKey(propertyName)) {
      return _mapRep[propertyName];
    }
    throw ArgumentError('propery not found');
  }
}

main() {
  Person person = Person(age: 10, name: 'Bob');

  print(person.name); // 'Bob'

  print(person.get('name')); // 'Bob'
  print(person.get('age')); // 10

  // wrong property name
  print(person.get('wrong')); // throws error
}
```

I tried a lot of ways, but no success yet.

Comment: You can't.  Flutter does not support runtime reflection, which would be expensive and would not provide type-safety.  Perhaps you could use a static, code-generation-based approach (such as [`package:reflectable`](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable)). Otherwise, if you need something dynamic, then use a `Map<String, Object?>` or `Map<String, dynamic>` as you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  try {
    print(person.get("wrong"));
  } on Error catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

Output:

```
Invalid argument(s): propery not found
```